# Open locations through application finder?

Tags: xubuntu, shortcut-keys, shortcuts, application-finder

It would be really fast to open most used folders by an application finder or something like that. It worked quite well in windows pressing win+r and type name of a folder shortcut in System32 folder.

Is it possible to do something like that in Xubuntu too?

E.g. Win+R to open application finder (or something similar) and type "Do" to open dowloads folder?

How would you do that? Now I need to open default folder and then click to a left panel. I understand it's easier to assign a shortcut to each location but that's not managable if you have many locations. I don't really like docks neither because Cairo always got stucked and did some troubles to me...

How would you solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, solution that actually works immediately is to use "custom actions" in Application Finder preferences.

```
Pattern: name_you_want_to_type
Command: pcmanfm '/home/user/folder/folder'
```

Works like a charm.

So you can easily "rename" applications too.

```
Pattern: writer
Command: /usr/bin/wps %f
```

(for Kingston Writer, e.g.)

Done.

Answer (score 1):

On Ubuntu Saucy 13.10, Win+R does exactly what you want, it opens the Application Finder in Xbuntu (XFCE).

exo-desktop-item-edit --create-new --name='downloads' --command='thunar /root/shared/downloads' ~/.local/share/applications

A GUI will pop up to edit the item further. The item will appear in a Application submenu called 'Other'

Then simply hit Win+R -> 'item name'

to setup a lot of these, add this to your .bashrc

```
function launchy(){
    if [ -z "$1" ]; then
        echo "missing abs path"
        return
    fi
    exo-desktop-item-edit --create-new --name="$1" --comment="thunar $1" ~/.local/share/applications
}
```

For some reason, the --command arg is not working, so I just cut paste from comment to command in the GUI.

Usage:
launchy /root/logs

win+R logs

Answer (score 0):

http://launchy.net/ is amazing on Windows and also 'works' on linux (was a little buggy).

A nice hack, you 'add favourites' eg: your download folder, in Explorer window, then add 'C:\Documents and Settings\user\Favourites' to the Launchy index, then Alt+Space 'download' jumps to that folder.

The same setup can be done via symlinks on linux, although less intuitive than the 'add favorite' button.